# FileStreamResult vs FileContentResult

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I have a method

```
public virtual FileContentResult DownloadUserFileTemplate()
{
    var dataRow = new DataRow { RowItems = new List<string> { "Name", "Email", "Roles" } };            
    var templateFileInMemoryStream = documentHandler.CsvDocumentCreator.Create(new List<DataRow> { dataRow }); //CsvDocumentCreator.Create method create stream object in using block and returns it.
    return File(templateFileInMemoryStream.ToArray(), "text/csv", "UserImportSheet.csv");
}
```

As we know that FileStreamResult also exist. So If I refactor above code as:

```
public virtual FileStreamResult DownloadUserFileTemplate()
{          
    var dataRow = new DataRow { RowItems = new List<string> { "Name", "Email", "Roles" } };
    var templateFileInMemoryStream = documentHandler.CsvDocumentCreator.Create(new List<DataRow> { dataRow });
    return File(templateFileInMemoryStream, "text/csv", "UserImportSheet.csv");
}
```

When I try to download file using above, it throws an exception that Stream has already been closed. Exception occurs somewhere after return statement as the above method does not throw any exception. Any ideas?

This is my CsvDocumentCreator.Create() Method:

```
 public MemoryStream Create(IList<DataRow> rows)
            {
                rows.IsNotNull("rows");

                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    foreach (var rowItem in row.RowItems)
                    {
                        builder.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(rowItem)).Append(",");
                    }

                    builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
                }

                return GenerateStream(builder.ToString());
            }



private static MemoryStream GenerateStream(string value)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(value);
                return stream;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. Is that the actual code? You're not wrapping `templateFileInMemoryStream` in a `using` block or something?

Comment: yes I am wraping it in using block but I am not sure what time it dispose/close the memory stream as it throws exception after action method is executed.

Comment: As it is always good practice to use using block for memory stream write so not sure why we got FileStreamResult because memorystream would be closed before this step.

Comment: added more code above to elaborate it further.

Comment: The problem is you're disposing the MemoryStream with the `using` block. Don't do that, from memory the FileStreamResult does it (it decompile the source once).

Comment: If my other code which is creating/disposing memory stream is in separate dll, how would i acheive this. I can not change that code as i do not know if some one will dispose my memory stream object or not. so question is if i was not using FileStreamResult, I was not explicitly closing that memory stream if it was not closed at service level? Is it not bad?

Comment: Note that `using` calls `Dispose`. [MSDN has this to say about `Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx): *This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using* The code in the external library is wrong because it disposes the object too early: the object will still be used.

Comment: *"I can not change that code as i do not know if some one will dispose my memory stream object or not."* You need to change that code regardless, because there is no way the `Create()` method returns a usable `MemoryStream`